# How to make group of buttons same width in SwiftUI

Tags: button, swiftui

I have a group of three buttons for media control (jump back, play/pause, jump forward). When I press the play button, the "play" icon is replaced by the "pause" icon which takes a bit less space. As I haven't defined any size constraints, the pause button gets a little bit smaller and causes the other two to move a bit.

How can I make all three buttons the same width without defining any hard constraints as currently the buttons have the perfect size on all different devices?

Simplified code:

```
HStack {
    Button(action: { }) {
        Image(systemName: "backward.end")
    }.padding().
    viewModel.isPlaying ? Button(action: { }) {
        Image(systemName: "pause")
    }.padding() : Button(action: { }) {
        Image(systemName: "play")
    }.padding()
    Button(action: { }) {
        Image(systemName: "forward.end")
    }.padding()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doing something similar with an audio player also.  My method is just to place an invisible (`.opacity(0.0)`) duplicate of the largest view in a `ZStack` so that the size doesn't jump.

```swift
ZStack {
  Image(systemName: "larger-button-image")
    .opacity(0.0)
    Image(systemName: "smaller-button-image")  
}
```

Comment: I've used it a lot with UILabels also.  For example, if you have a clock/ticker use an invisible UILabel with `.text = "00:00:00"` for layout and put your actual content on top of it (leading/trailing as appropriate).  Now the layout won't shift with every tick.  Much easier with SwiftUI though!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the difference in size then you can pad the images by different amounts
i.e. `Image(systemName: "bigger").padding(.horizontal, 1)` and `Image(systemName: "smaller").padding(.horizontal, 5)`.

You can also wrap the conditional expression in a VStack and then apply a frame to the VStack so that it becomes a fixed width. You will probably want to centre the images in the VStack.

The play.circle and pause.circle seem to be more like the same size or you could use the playpause image.

Finally you can export the symbols using the SF Symbols app and fix them.